# Consume Salesforce Analytics Cloud External Data Rest API using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce

I am new to Ruby on rails and Salesforce.  I want to upload some external data to [Salesforce Analytics Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/), but I do not have any information about their respective api's. The only information available is related to java jar file consumption.

Does anyone have an example of how to upload data into the Saleforce Analytics Cloud from a ruby on rails application?